# Rendered bean method doesn't get called on rendering of panelDialog?

Tags: jsf

I'm using ibm jsf 1.2. I have main form with button on it. When the button is pressed new panel dialog is opened with a field which should be rendered according to some validation.

Here is my .jsp file:

```
<hx:jspPanel>
<fieldset>
<h:panelGrid
<hx:commandExButton type="button"
value="#{msg.buttonAddContainer}" id="chooseContainerButton">
<hx:behavior event="onclick" behaviorAction="get;show"
id="behavior2" targetAction="gridListContainers;containerDialog" />
</hx:commandExButton>
</h:panelGrid>
</fieldset>
</hx:jspPanel>


<hx:panelDialog type="modal" id="containerDialog"
noKeybindings="true" showTitleCloseButton="false"
onshow="openDialog()" onhide="closeDialog()"
styleClass="panelDialog" title="#{msg.lblContainer}">

<h:panelGrid id="gridContainerNumber">
<h:outputLabel for="inputContainerNumber"></h:outputLabel>
<h:inputText id="inputContainerNumber" styleClass="inputText">
<!-- some other field - container number-->
<h:message for="inputContainerNumber" id="messageInputContainerNumber">    </h:message>

<h:outputLabel id="labelInputBookingNumber" styleClass="outputLabel"
for="inputBookingNumber" value="#{msg.lblBookingNumber}" 
    rendered="#{myBean.isBookingNumberRendered}">
</h:outputLabel>
<h:inputText id="inputBookingNumber" immediate="true"
value="#{myBean.bookingNumber}"
rendered="#{myBean.isBookingNumberRendered}" styleClass="inputText">
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="mesageInputBookingNumber"
styleClass="message" for="inputBookingNumber"
rendered="#{myBean.isBookingNumberRendered}">
</h:message>
</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGroup id="groupClear" styleClass="buttonGroup">
<hx:commandExButton id="submitButton"
styleClass="positive"
action="#{myBean.saveContainer}"
type="submit" immediate="true" value="#{msg.buttonSave}">
</hx:commandExButton>
<hx:commandExButton id="cancelButton"
styleClass="negative"
action="#{myBean.clearContainer}"
type="submit" immediate="true" value="#{msg.buttonCancel}">
<hx:behavior event="onclick" behaviorAction="get;hide" id="behavior6"
targetAction="helpBox1;containerDialog"></hx:behavior>
</hx:commandExButton>
</h:panelGroup>

<hx:ajaxRefreshSubmit target="gridListContainers" id="ajaxSubmit1"
onstart="showProgressBar();" oncomplete="hideProgressBar();">
</hx:ajaxRefreshSubmit>
</hx:panelDialog>
```

Rendered on panelDialog is not behaving as I would expect. Rendering check method isBookingNumberRendered isn't called when dialog opens for the first time, so booking number field isn't shown when the validation criteria is met. When I enter the other field on dialogPanel and hit Save button (isBookingNumberRendered is called) and then hit choose containerButton again the field is shown.
Why doesn't the isBookingNumberRendered method get called for the first time when the panelDialog is rendered?
Please help.

Best regards,
mismas

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :)
I had:

```
<hx:behavior event="onclick" behaviorAction="get;show"
id="behavior2" targetAction="gridListContainers;containerDialog" />
```

where `gridListContainers` where not id of panel grid `<h:panelGrid id="gridContainerNumber">`
So I have just changed it to `<h:panelGrid id="gridListContainers">`  and it worked fine.
It is very ungrateful that nothing is complaining, you just get strange behaviour ...